# Knockout.js and Isotope

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to get knockout to work with isotope.  I seem to be running into a problem where the style that isotope requires is getting stomped on by knockout.

Here is the generated html from knockout.  In particular note the style on the div

```
<div class="photo isotope-item" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; ">
  <img data-bind="attr: { src: imageSource}" src="/images/1.jpg">
</div>
```

What isotope needs is to be able to position the div

```
<div class="photo  isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(245px, 5px, 0px); ">
        <img src="images/1.jpg">
</div>
```

Is there a way to get knockout to work with isotope?

Comment: What's the issue exactly? The lack of the webkit-transform? Can you post the KO template prior to generation.

Comment: Is knockout really touching your div? there is no data-bind attribute on it, so knockout should just leave it alone. As far as your template goes, you're specifying a stacking src attribute and a dynamic one that knockout will interpolate for you. Is that your intent?

Comment: Isotope must have this element.style {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); otherwise, its layout-logic can't work. Since Isotope can be customised to do so very many things - can't you just let go of knockout.js?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what goes wrong in your case, but you might want to try this Isotope binding I've written for Knockout, [Knockout-Isotope](https://github.com/aknuds1/knockout-isotope). Mind that it requires a forked version of [Knockout](https://github.com/aknuds1/knockout). I can elaborate if you'd like to know more.